# web.config rewrite rule from subdomain to folder using root web.configs connection string

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc, web.config

We have a rewrite rule in place to forward demo.website.com to the subfolder which contains the Demo website (website.com/Demo).

The problem is that it is still using the root web.configs db connection, instead of the connection string in wwwroot\Demo\web.config.

Here is the rule:

```
<rule name="demo rewrite" enabled="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^demo\.website\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="Demo/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Downvote: Care to explain? Or was this just a drive-by downvote?

Comment: So when accessing website.com/demo directly without a rewrite the database connection string is correct? Is /demo its own application?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf correct, when accessing directly the correct DB connection is used. /Demo is its own application under the Default Web Site.